# qt slots currying

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, currying

Is there a way curry qt slot? Maybe there is something similar to curryng?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166051/binding-arguments-to-signals-slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use QSignalMapper to bind connect some signals to it and then connect it's own signals to target slots with some parameters attached.

```
// connect signal to mapper
signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
signalMapper->setMapping(button1, QString("param1"));
signalMapper->setMapping(button2, QString("param2"));
connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));

// connect mapper signal to slot
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)), this, SLOT(originalSlot(const QString &)));
```

Comment: I think that the second `connect` call should say `button2`, not `button1`.  I presume that is the magic that would make this technique useful: to have the signal mapper respond differently to unique senders.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not possible directly using Qt, some binding/currying is available through [LibQxt](http://libqxt.org). For example and from the docs of [QxtBoundFunction](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src/2dd3424cb69d/src/core/qxtboundfunction.h):

> By far, the most common expected use is to provide a parameter to a slot when the
>        signal doesn't have offer one. Many developers new to Qt try to write code like this:
>        \code
>            connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), lineEdit, SLOT(setText("Hello, world")));
>        \endcode
>        Experienced Qt developers will immediately spot the flaw here. The typical solution
>        is to create a short, one-line wrapper slot that invokes the desired function. Some
>        clever developers may even use QSignalMapper to handle slots that only need one
>        int or QString parameter.
>
> QxtBoundFunction enables the previous connect statement to be written like this:
>        \code
>            connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), QxtMetaObject::bind(lineEdit,
>                  SLOT(setText(QString)), Q_ARG(QString, "Hello, world!")));
>        \code
>        This accomplishes the same result without having to create a new slot, or worse,
>        an entire object, just to pass a constant value.
>
> Additionally, through the use of the QXT_BIND macro, parameters from the signal
>        can be rearranged, skipped, or passed alongside constant arguments provided
>        with the Q_ARG macro. This can be used to provide stateful callbacks to a
>        generic function, for example.
>
> Many kinds of functions can be bound. The most common binding applies to
>        Qt signals and slots, but standard C/C++ functions can be bound as well.
>        Future development may add the ability to bind to C++ member functions,
>        and developers can make custom QxtBoundFunction subclasses for even more
>        flexibility if necessary.

Although I have submitted some patches to LibQxt, I haven't used this directly so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Binding arguments is not possible using Qt signal/slots. You'll have to use boost::signals and  boost::bind instead to achieve such functionality.

Comment: LibQxt is also an option, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, now we have Qt 5 and the ability to connect signals to arbitrary callable objects:

```
connect(sender, &MyClass::mySignal, receiver, std::bind(&OtherClass::mySlot, boundArg));

connect(sender, &MyClass::mySignal, receiver, [=] { receiver->mySlot(boundArg); });
```